# Exclude specific files by extension from git log

Tags: git

I need to exclude specific files depending of its extension, my command now is this:

```
git log --author="author.name" --pretty=tformat: --numstat
```

What I should add to exclude for example all files with extension .ktr and .db_diagram?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With grep:

```
git log --author="author.name" --pretty=tformat: --numstat | grep -v -E '*\.(klr|db_diagram)$'
```

Comment: Hi! I've tried but it'snt excluding the files with these extensions .

Comment: I edited my answer, but I don't think that will fix the issue. What OS are you running ? Which shell ?

Comment: Great, anyway, the [ElpieKay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6330106/elpiekay)'s answer works too - it's not the usual way of doing, but it works great and is valid too. Just sayin' :)

Comment: Using `grep` removes the colors I get from `git log -p` unfortunately. I want to e.g. exclude changes to a lock file.

Answer (score 6):

`git log --author="author.name" --pretty=tformat: --numstat -- . ':!*.ktr' ':!*.db_diagram'`

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
git log --author="author.name" --pretty=tformat: --numstat | grep -v -E '*.ktr|*.db_diagram'
```